# Incorrect SVN console messages in Mars and Neon

Tags: version-control, notifications, message, subclipse

In Mars and Neon, Subclipse returns notify.at (or  notify.update  notify.stats.file.head   notify.stats.update) instead of revision number message (like " At revision 1738") on update to head. Works OK in Luna.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be related to Eclipse version. You are probably using SVN 1.9 client and we received a new notification event from the API that we do not have code in place to handle.

Could you file an issue here with some details?

https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse